# win32 threads in Qt

Tags: winapi, qt

Is there a way to create a thread in Qt without using subclassing (ie. making a QThread class)? It's getting difficult sending data into the thread. Is is possible to use win32 threads in Qt if so can someone give me an example on how to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't necessarily subclass QThread - See discussion here http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have many simple tasks and want to have them processed in threaded fashion. [`QRunnable`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qrunnable.html) and [`QThreadPool`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qthreadpool.html) provide a quick and easy approach without dealing with threads themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run a function in another thread you should check the [QT Concurrent Namespace.](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/threads-qtconcurrent.html)

The following example will run the function 'aFunction()' in separate thread and will not block on the line where calling the function. Of course there are mechanisms to understand when a function ends, to get a result, to wait for it.

```
void aFunction(int arg1, double arg2, const QString &string);

int integer = ...;
double floatingPoint = ...;
QString string = ...;

QtConcurrent::run(aFunction, integer, floatingPoint, string);
```